# How to get all appointments including the private ones?

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to list all Outlook appointment times in a specific time range and I am only interested in start and end time of the appointments.

I'm using this code so far:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

var outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");

var recip = outlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("<valid contact>");

if (recip.Resolve())
{
    var calendarItems = outlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items;
    calendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;

    var filter = String.Format("[Start] >= '{0}' And [End] < '{1}'", startTime.ToShortDateString(), endTime.ToShortDateString());

    calendarItems.Sort("[Start]");
    calendarItems = calendarItems.Restrict(filter);

    var result = calendarItems.Cast<AppointmentItem>().Select(x => x);
}
```

The code retrieves nearly all appointments, but not the private ones. How can I get the private appointments too?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook always filters out private appointments form the shared folders even if they are perfectly accessible using MAPI. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use [RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).`GetActivitiesForTimeRange` - it returns private appointments.